# Jquery scrollTop animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an animation that needs to kick in once scrollTop() hits a given position on a page. That part is working fine, but what I want is for the animation to reverse when I scroll back up the page, returning the element to it's original position.

http://cdpn.io/dphBx

The code in my example is working fine and the JS is identical to the site I'm working on locally, but in Chrome the element doesn't return to it's original position when you scroll back up the page. JQuery is the only Javascript I'm linking to, so no conflicts, and there isn't anything in the CSS that should be preventing it either. I'm still pretty green when it comes to JQuery, so bear with me. I'm thinking maybe an if/else statement isn't the best way to accomplish this? Any thoughts?

Comment: Works fine here on Chrome 31. Though I would use `$(window).scrollTop` instead of `body`.

Comment: It works for me also, in Chrome 31, but there is a slight delay before the animation fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me, using Chrome 31 on a Mac. However, you should try the following modifications to improve the performance:

1. Use `.stop(true, true)` before chaining the animation, so that you ensure the animation goes to completion.
2. Throttle or debounce the resize event so it is not fired too often, saving the number of calculations needed to be performed, and prevents quickly toggling between two animation end states too often.
3. Get the scroll position with `$(window).scrollTop()` instead of on the body.

I have decided to use the jQuery throttle+debounce plugin available here: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-throttle-debounce/1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll($.throttle(100, function(){
    var position = $("window").scrollTop();
    if(position >= 200){
      $("#foo").stop(true,true).animate({left: "200px"}, "fast");
    } else{
      $("#foo").stop(true,true).animate({left: 0}, "fast");
    }
  }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Terry! Can you explain how throttle/debounce works? And is there a similar functionality included in JQuery for that? I'm trying not to rely on plugins so I can get as in-depth as possible.

Comment: Also, I'm still really confused about how stop() works. It seems counterintuitive that it ensures that the animation completes.

Comment: @Brad The issue with jQuery animation is that it queues - in other words, animations can be seen as individual events that will take place after each other depending on the order they are added to the element. In this case, if you scroll up and down quickly between the 200px threshold, you will cause a whole lot of `.animate()` to be added, and queued, causing the browser to lag and FPS to fall due to constant need to reposition `#foo`.

Comment: @Brad What `.stop(true, true)` does is that you tell the element, "hey, drop what you're doing right now, move immediately to end state, and continue with the latest animation I gave you".

For throttling, you can of course use setTimeOut() and make some tweaks yourself, but I rely I jQuery plugins because it's way more convenient. On how it works, check this link out: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/